# Xcode playground no assistant editor output

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift-playground

i started using Xcode Playground. Apparently you can show your output in the assistant editor if you press the little plus next to the type value results. but the only thing that happens with my playground is, that it opens a little window inside my code, there it shows the graph. No matter what it won't show anything in my assistant editor. does anyone know how to fix that ?

Comment: The title of the linked Q&A is different but my answer addresses your issue.

Comment: @Eric Aya thanks everything works except for the assistant editor output. It only gives me the error of an unresolved identifier for the XCPCaptureValue

Comment: `XCPCaptureValue` is deprecated and doesn't work well anymore anyway... :/

Comment: @EricAya but i've seen people on youtube using assistant Editor/timeline without using XCPCaptureValue. Do you know how it works for them ?

Comment: You can display many things in the Assistant Editor (see my answers about Playgrounds: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a2227743%20playground) but you can't capture values anymore to show them in graphs in AE, and there's no alternative yet.